# Exception handling plan for c++ plugin application

Tags: c++, exception

We are developing plugin dll for C++ MFC application. In our plugin functions are throwing exceptions if they can't fulfill its post conditions. Usually the exceptions are caught by the higher context, but sometimes they propagate up to the event handlers and the application crashes. So, I am writing, in every event handler try/catch block in order to avoid the application to crash and show informative message that unexpected error occurred. I was thinking if there is way to skip this. Maybe set global unexpected handler, with set_unexpected function, but again this is unreliable and someone else like third party libraries can overwrite my exception handler. Anyone has some suggestion

Answer (score 1):

When crossing "unit" boundaries such as C-C++ interfaces or shared object boundaries, exceptions need to be caught and propagated back in a way that both sides of the interface can recognize. Unfortunately there's no easy way to do this as you discovered.

Comment: Returning error values (similar to how COM handles it) works relatively well. You just make sure to handle the exception within the function that might throw and all info goes in the return (can even copy necessary info from a caught exception and pass it).